# $.post function not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

The onchange function can run properly but I face some problem that the $.post function is not working

Here is html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="3" onchange="checkradio(this.value)"/>
```

Here is javascript

```
var total=0;
function checkradio(serid) {
var num = 0;
$.post( "getserprice.php",{ serid: serid}, function( data ) {
          alert(data);
          num = data;
      })
 if (document.getElementById('chk').checked) {
        total = total + num;
    } else {
        total = total - num;
    }
}
```

Here is PHP

```
$price = 3;
echo $price;
```

Comment: can you share sample fiddle? Any exception on console? Is your method getting called?

Comment: How do you mean it's not working? what do you expect it to work compared to it is currently working?

Comment: explain what your have to done and what your getting from server side ?

Comment: The alert in $.post function din't show but if i put alert outside the $.post function it can be work

Comment: try exit end of code like this  $price = 3;
echo $price; exit;

Comment: @user6652240 That probably means there was an error on the server side, check the logs or use the developer tools to see what's going on. It could be that the URL should be `/getserprice.php`

Comment: thanks, i found that there's some problem in my server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but `num` won't be set to anything when it is used in the conditional below the success callback passed to `$.post`. You should change the function to this:

```
function checkradio(serid) {

    var num = 0;
    $.post( "getserprice.php",{ serid: serid}, function( data ) {
          alert(data);
          num = data;
          if (document.getElementById('chk').checked) {
              total = total + num;
          } else {
              total = total - num;
          }
      })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

$.post is an asynchronous function, i.e; when it makes a call it won't wait for the success event to occur and get data. Instead it will execute the next if conditional without even getting the data. So, we will get unexpected results.

```
var total=0;
function checkradio(serid) {
var num = 0;
$.post( "getserprice.php",{ serid: serid}, function( data ) {
          alert(data);
          num = data;
          if (document.getElementById('chk').checked) {
             total = total + num;
          } else {
             total = total - num;
          }
}
```